# Asymptotic order of a recursive function

Tags: recurrence-relation

\begin{gather*} 
T(n)=T(\frac{n}{\log n})+O(1)
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
T(1)=O(1)
\end{gather*}
I try to use substitution method to solve $T(n)$, but because of $\log n$ get stuck. Can we use substitution method for solving $T(n)$?

My attempt:
One step of my extending of $T(n)$:
\begin{gather*} 
T(n)=T(\frac{n}{\log n})+O(1)=T(\frac{\frac{n}{\log n}}{\log \frac{n}{\log n}})+O(1)+O(1)
\end{gather*}

Comment: The initial condition is not useful unless the recurrence relation is something like $$T(n)=T(\lfloor\frac{n}{\log n}\rfloor)+O(1)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, we prove lower bound as follow:

Suppose in each iteration we divide $n$ to $\log k$ so we define new fuction $a_k(n)$ as follow:

\begin{gather*} 
a_k(n) =a_k\left(\frac{n}{\log k}\right)  
\end{gather*}

If $k<<n$ then after using substitution method we have :
\begin{gather*} 
a_k(n) =a_k\left(\frac{n}{\log^t k}\right) + \overbrace{O(1)+O(1)+...+O(1)}^\text{t times} 
\end{gather*}

So for find value of $t$:

\begin{gather*} 
\left(\frac{n}{\log^t k}=1\right) 
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
n=\log^t k
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
t=\log_{\log k}n.
\end{gather*}

As a result,
\begin{gather*} 
T(n)=\Omega\left(\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}\right).
\end{gather*}
For upper bound  we do trickly:
As mentioned in [this post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10242/how-many-steps-does-this-recurrence-take-to-get-to-2-or-1)

Now we define $a_k(n)$ as follow:
$$
a_k(n) = \begin{cases}
   a_k\left(\frac{n}{\log k}\right) + O(1) & \text{if } n \ge k, 
   \\
   T(n) & \text{otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}
$$

As you see $T(n)\leq a_k(n)$ for $k\leq n$ so we set $k=\sqrt{n}$ and we have
$$ a_k(n)\leq T(\sqrt{n})+O\left(\frac{\log \frac{n}{k}}{\log\log k}\right)$$
$$ T(n)\leq T(\sqrt{n})+O\left(\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}\right)$$

Multiply side of inequality by $\log\log n$:

$$ T(n)\log\log n\leq T(\sqrt{n})\log\log n+O\left(\log n\right)$$

$$ T(n)\log\log n\leq T(\sqrt{n})\log(\log (\sqrt{n}\times\sqrt{n})) +O\left(\log n\right)$$

$$= T(n)\log\log n\leq T(\sqrt{n})\log(\log \sqrt{n}+\log\sqrt{n}) +O\left(\log n\right)$$

$$= T(n)\log\log n\leq T(\sqrt{n})\log(\log \sqrt{n}(2)) +O\left(\log n\right)$$

$$= T(n)\log\log n\leq T(\sqrt{n})(\log\log \sqrt{n}+\log 2) +O\left(\log n\right)$$
$$= T(n)\log\log n\leq T(\sqrt{n})(\log\log \sqrt{n}+1) +O\left(\log n\right)$$

So we define
$$H(n)=T(n)\log\log n$$
As a result we have:

$$= H(n)\leq T(\sqrt{n})+H(\sqrt{n}) +O\left(\log n\right)$$

We show that $T(n)\leq O(\log n)$:

$$T(n)=T\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)+O(1)\leq T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+O(1)$$

So

$$= H(n)\leq H(\sqrt{n}) +O\left(\log n\right)$$

Finally with substitution method:

$$= H(n)\leq H\left(n^{\frac{1}{2^k}}\right) +O\left(\log n\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\dots + \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\right)$$

We know that $k=\log\log n$, and becuase of :
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\dots + \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\right)\leq 2$$ then
$$ H(n)\leq O\left(\log n\right)$$

As the result $$T(n)\leq O\left(\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}\right)$$
We prove upper bound and lower bound of $T(n)$ so
$$T(n)\leq \theta\left(\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is really, how many times do you need to apply the transformation $m \mapsto \frac{m}{\log m}$ in order for a value to drop from $n$ below some constant $C$; if the answer is $f(n)$, then $T(n) = \Theta(f(n))$.

Given $n$, define a sequence by $n_0 = n$ and $n_{i+1} = n_i/ \log n_i$. We would like to know the minimal value of $t$ which satisfies $n_t < C$.

Taking logarithm, we see that $\log n_{i+1} = \log n_i - \log\log n_i \geq \log n_i - \log\log n$. Since $\log n_0 = \log n$, this shows that $t \gtrsim \frac{\log n}{\log\log n}$.

In the other direction, as long as $n_i \geq \sqrt{n}$, we have $\log n_{i+1} \leq \log n_i - \log \log \sqrt{n} \leq \log n_i - \log \log n + \log(1/2)$. Hence we get from $n$ down to $\sqrt{n}$ in roughly $\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}$ steps. We then get down to $\sqrt[4]{n}$ in roughly $\frac{\log \sqrt{n}}{\log\log \sqrt{n}} \approx \frac{\frac{1}{2} \log n}{\log\log n}$ steps. Continuing in this way, we see that $t \lesssim \frac{2\log n}{\log\log n}$ (summing the series $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} + \cdots = 2$).